# Data in legend doesnt match the displayed data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have code that plot tabular data I have . The code choose everytime different row (observation) to plot and  display the data and the legend with the name of the observations.

My problem is that  that even if I change the displayed data using the iloc (e.g changing the rows to be displayed) , I still get the same legend .
for example:

If I use this code, that suppose to display rows 0-10:

```
SavitzkyGolay(db_plants.iloc[:10,5:],25,2).T.plot(title='25/06/2019 17:00',figsize=(17,10))
plt.legend(db_plants['plant'])
```

The result I get is this :

[image]

But when I change the iloc:

```
SavitzkyGolay(db_plants.iloc[12:22,5:],25,2).T.plot(title='25/06/2019 17:00',figsize=(17,10))
plt.legend(db_plants['plant'])
```

I get the same legend:
[image]

*I can't share the original dataframe
*The observations names are different for sure

My end goal: to have the correct observations displayed in the legend

EDIT: I have used the iloc :

```
SavitzkyGolay(db_plants.iloc[12:22,5:],25,2).T.plot(title='25/06/201917:00',figsize=(17,10))
plt.legend(db_plants['plant'].iloc[12:22,5:])
```

But I still gett error:

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: Since you have the same line of code creating the legend in both cases, both cases show the same legend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I thought it  knows to legend the correct ones. how can I control it?

Comment: Use the same .iloc to the legends you use

Comment: @JulienRoulle I get the error of too many indexers